# RSS/ATOM feed reader for windows (or cross-platform)

Tags: xml, rss, cross-platform

Looking for a good rss/feed reader for windows or if there are any good cross platforms one i would be really amazed, or good web services (dont like the google one).

I want something simplistic and minimalistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the NewsGator family of tools (http://newsgator.com).  I mostly use the Mac and web-based versions, but thought FeedDemon was good, too, for the Windows environment.  All keep a common subscription list, so you can bounce back and forth as needed.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call it minimalistic, but [FeedDemon](http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/FeedDemon/Default.aspx) is the best I've found for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Google reader and quite happy with it. Its browser based but has good keyboard support. Check http://www.google.com/reader

Answer (score 0):

I use [Net Vibes](http://www.netvibes.com) it's an online Rss collator that allows you to split your feeds up into multiple topics. I used to use Thunderbird but I can access netvibes from wherever I am. I can also set it up to keep track of my email and social networking sites as there are a bunch of widgets available for it.

Answer (score 0):

Some people enjoy [RSS Bandit](http://www.rssbandit.org/), but I'm on a Mac now so I'm not sure how current it is.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007

Attensa (can plug into outlook 2003)

newsgator

Internet explorer 8

Mozilla Firefox

I am yet to find a good free windows rss reader with decent offline capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GreatNews](http://www.curiostudio.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Wizz RSS, a Firefox plugin. Works ok. I am using mainly to access [Sun Java forums](http://forums.sun.com/index.jspa).

http://www.wizzrss.com/Welcome.php

Answer (score 0):

Y Use A Rss Reader,,, When You Can get the articles.. Go To The Link

[TNB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/thenewsbook/)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Google account already, seriously consider Google Reader. It's available everywhere, with Gears installed it is available offline and binds well to Firefox and Chrome.